# ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Invalid parameter information was passed to method 'differential.getcommitmessage', could not decode JSON serialization

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Suddenly my calls to `arc diff` no longer work, it seems that there is a problem with JSON serialization. Any guidance greatly appreciated!

```
$ arc diff master
Exception
ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Invalid parameter information was passed to method 'differential.getcommitmessage', could not decode JSON serialization. Data: {"revision_id":null,"edit":"create","fields":{"title":"Issue #LFT-319 description of my issue"},"__conduit__":{"sessionKey":"5xxxxxx7tnhm6f7pcedd2evfwtlyhhjtem24wxby","c
(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
49$ arc diff master --trace
libphutil loaded from '/Applications/phabricator/libphutil/src'.
arcanist loaded from '/Applications/phabricator/arcanist/src'.
Config: Reading user configuration file "/Users/me/.arcrc"...
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Unable to find .arcconfig in any of these locations: /Users/me/Documents/dev/vagrant/drupal/project/.arcconfig.
Working Copy: Path "/Users/me/Documents/dev/vagrant/drupal/project/sites/all/modules" is part of `git` working copy "/Users/me/Documents/dev/vagrant/drupal/project".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/Users/me/Documents/dev/vagrant/drupal/project".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/Users/me/Documents/dev/vagrant/drupal/project/.git/arc/config".
>>> [0] <conduit> conduit.connect() <bytes = 490>
>>> [1] <http> https://phabricator.example.org/api/conduit.connect
<<< [1] <http> 663,084 us
<<< [0] <conduit> 665,692 us
>>> [2] <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --raw 'HEAD' --
>>> [3] <exec> $ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
<<< [3] <exec> 80,427 us
<<< [2] <exec> 286,142 us
>>> [4] <exec> $ git diff-files --name-only
<<< [4] <exec> 20,853 us
>>> [5] <event> diff.didCollectChanges <listeners = 0>
<<< [5] <event> 162 us
>>> [6] <exec> $ git rev-parse 'HEAD'
<<< [6] <exec> 8,002 us
>>> [7] <exec> $ git merge-base 'master' 'b13c62361bc01039c218d1275ae070a186cac15c'
<<< [7] <exec> 10,360 us
>>> [8] <exec> $ git log --first-parent --format=medium '56b4bc77e0b3782587842f596b31944166402d46'..'b13c62361bc01039c218d1275ae070a186cac15c'
<<< [8] <exec> 9,277 us
>>> [9] <exec> $ git log 'b13c62361bc01039c218d1275ae070a186cac15c' --not '56b4bc77e0b3782587842f596b31944166402d46' --format='%H%x01%T%x01%P%x01%at%x01%an%x01%aE%x01%s%x01%s%n%n%b%x02' --
<<< [9] <exec> 9,929 us
>>> [10] <conduit> differential.query() <bytes = 416>
>>> [11] <http> https://phabricator.example.org/api/differential.query
<<< [11] <http> 196,046 us
<<< [10] <conduit> 196,493 us
>>> [12] <exec> $ git rev-parse --git-dir
<<< [12] <exec> 8,543 us
>>> [13] <exec> $ git log 'xxxxxx61bc01039c218d1275ae070a186cac15c' --not 'xxxxxx7e0b3782587842f596b31944166402d46' --format='%H%x01%T%x01%P%x01%at%x01%an%x01%aE%x01%s%x01%s%n%n%b%x02' --
<<< [13] <exec> 8,681 us
>>> [14] <conduit> differential.parsecommitmessage() <bytes = 268>
>>> [15] <http> https://phabricator.example.org/api/differential.parsecommitmessage
<<< [15] <http> 208,029 us
<<< [14] <conduit> 208,366 us
>>> [16] <event> diff.willBuildMessage <listeners = 0>
<<< [16] <event> 154 us
>>> [17] <conduit> differential.getcommitmessage() <bytes = 320>
>>> [18] <http> https://phabricator.example.org/api/differential.getcommitmessage
<<< [18] <http> 169,571 us
<<< [17] <conduit> 169,903 us

[2015-07-27 22:21:21] EXCEPTION: (ConduitClientException) ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Invalid parameter information was passed to method 'differential.getcommitmessage', could not decode JSON serialization. Data: {"revision_id":null,"edit":"create","fields":{"title":"Issue #LFT-319 initial code to avoid processing failing orders"},"__conduit__":{"sessionKey":"xxxxxxlmknfudwo2wqb4szp3dskh3qa3fmq6wulx","c at [<phutil>/src/conduit/ConduitFuture.php:58]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=9a7c4d87a850), phutil(head=master, ref.master=81eed10bea57)
  #0 ConduitFuture::didReceiveResult(array) called at [<phutil>/src/future/FutureProxy.php:58]
  #1 FutureProxy::getResult() called at [<phutil>/src/future/FutureProxy.php:35]
  #2 FutureProxy::resolve() called at [<phutil>/src/conduit/ConduitClient.php:58]
  #3 ConduitClient::callMethodSynchronous(string, array) called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistDiffWorkflow.php:1608]
  #4 ArcanistDiffWorkflow::getCommitMessageFromUser() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistDiffWorkflow.php:1511]
  #5 ArcanistDiffWorkflow::buildCommitMessage() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistDiffWorkflow.php:460]
  #6 ArcanistDiffWorkflow::run() called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:382]
```

Comment: This might be related to a cUrl problem, see https://secure.phabricator.com/T8654

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the other day, try to update your `libphutil` (which was required to install `arcanist`).